# Currency translation -- changing an elements place with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, localization, angular-translate

I am using angular-translate in my project and I have 2 languages in it(Turkish&English).

In Turkish, price of an item is written like this: 36₺,
but in the US, it's like: $9.

I don't want to use `ng-if` for every price in my project(there are lots of them) to change money sign's place.

So is there a shorter way to accomplish that?

Comment: you should take a look at the currency filter of angularjs

Comment: You can Build two file translate "TU" and "US" and add any key to be change and add the key in html page,select the two choice any language require of button.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions guys

Comment: See [AngularJS currency filter API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency).

Comment: See also [MDN JavaScript Reference `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

Comment: @georgeawg thanks for this useful resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider creating a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters) that uses [Number.prototype.toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

```js
console.log(Number(8).toLocaleString('en',{style: 'currency', currency: 'USD'}))
console.log(Number(8).toLocaleString('de',{style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
{{ lang == 'tr' ? '₺' + item.price : item.price + '$' }}
```

Or write your own [Custom Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#creating-custom-filters) that parses your currency.

Comment: That's a great solution. I was gonna use `ng-class` method, but it would require to add two classes to .css file, one function to .js file and and `ng-class` to .html file. This is so much shorter. Thanks!

Comment: Thanx, if you like the answer please accept as the answer :-)